# How do I pass an array as an argument to a WP-CLI command?

Tags: array, wp-insert-post, command-line, wp-cli

I want to use WP-CLI to create some new posts with custom taxonomy terms assigned. The challenge is that wp_insert_post's `tax_input` argument only accepts arrays, which I would have to specify on the command line. According to the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post), here is the format required:

```
$post = array(
    'tax_input' => [ array( 'taxonomy_name' => array( 'term', 'term2', 'term3' ) ) ] // support for custom taxonomies
}
```

But I need something like this:

```
wp post create --post_type=lecture --post_title='Test Post #1' --tax-input=[BIG FAT ARRAY]
```

So my idea was to write a PHP script that executes the WP-CLI command with the array serialized:

```
//DEFINE VARIABLES
$post_title = "Test Post #1";
$tax_items = array( 9,11,17 );
$tax_input = array( 'course' => $tax_items );

//SERIALIZE THIS ARRAY
$tax_escaped = escapeshellarg(serialize($tax_input));

//WRITE THE COMMAND
$exec_string = 'wp post create --post_type=lecture --post_status=publish --post_title="%1$s" --tax_input=%2$s --porcelain';
$exec_command = sprintf($exec_string, $post_title, $tax_escaped );
$post_id = shell_exec($exec_command);

//THE OUTPUT
//wp post create --post_type=lecture --post_status=publish --post_title="Test Post #1" --tax_input='a:1:{s:5:"class";a:3:{i:0;i:9;i:1;i:11;i:2;i:17;}}' --porcelain

//RELATE THE NEW POST TO THE TAXONOMY TERMS
wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $tax_items,'course');
```

Alas, this doesn't work. It creates the new post alright, but it fails to assign the 'course' taxonomy categories I want. Any help would be appreciated.

I know that this overall strategy works, because I succeeded in creating and taxonomizing my posts using `wp_insert_posts`. So this exercise is for educational purposes and future reference.

Comment: It does not seem to be possible. See the pull request: https://github.com/wp-cli/entity-command/pull/207

Answer (score 2):

This is probably impossible since WP-CLI pass the arguments directly to `wp_insert_posts`. I'm automating this with `wp eval`. For example:

```
wp eval 'wp_set_object_terms(12 , array(1, 2, 3), "course");'
```

The post id can be obtained when you create the post with `--porcelain`:

```
wp post create ... --porcelain
```

Or by normal query with post title:

```
wp eval 'wp_set_object_terms(get_page_by_title("Test Post #1", OBJECT, "lecture")->ID, array(1, 2, 3), "course");'
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally you'd pass an array to a script on the command line using the following

```
# Our array is named "foo"
php yourscript.php foo[]=bar&foo[]=baz&foo[some_key]=some_value
```

Answer (score 0):

It's 10 years old, but WP-CLI still doesn't handle the taxonomies while using `wp post create`.

So let's say you have the command:

`wp post create --post_type=book --post_title="The Book" --tax_input={"year":"2023", "section": "drama"}`

If you run it, wp-cli will create the post but not attach the taxonomies year and section with the terms "2023" and "drama", respectively, to the post.

I've found a hack to **temporarily** fix this (**You'll need to revert the changes after you run your wp-cli commands!**).

The steps are:

- Open the file `wp-includes/post.php`;
- Search for `if ( ! empty( $postarr['tax_input'] ) ) {`. As of today, it's on line **4564**

If you `var_dump($postarr['tax_input'])`, you'll see it's a string like `"{\"year\":\"2023\", \"section\": \"drama\"}"`. We need to remove the slashes and convert it to a php array.

So, **replace the code**:

```
    if ( ! empty( $postarr['tax_input'] ) ) {
        foreach ( $postarr['tax_input'] as $taxonomy => $tags ) {
            $taxonomy_obj = get_taxonomy( $taxonomy );

            if ( ! $taxonomy_obj ) {
                _doing_it_wrong( __FUNCTION__, sprintf( __( 'Invalid taxonomy: %s.' ), $taxonomy ), '4.4.0' );
                continue;
            }

            if ( is_array( $tags ) ) {
                $tags = array_filter( $tags );
            }

            if ( current_user_can( $taxonomy_obj->cap->assign_terms ) ) {
                wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $tags, $taxonomy );
            }
        }
    }
```

**With:**

```
    // Remove slashes
    $postarr['tax_input'] = stripslashes($postarr['tax_input']);

    // Convert json to array
    $postarr['tax_input'] = json_decode($postarr['tax_input']);

    // New-style support for all custom taxonomies.
    if ( ! empty( $postarr['tax_input'] ) ) {
        foreach ( $postarr['tax_input'] as $taxonomy => $tags ) {
            $taxonomy_obj = get_taxonomy( $taxonomy );

            if ( ! $taxonomy_obj ) {
                /* translators: %s: Taxonomy name. */
                _doing_it_wrong( __FUNCTION__, sprintf( __( 'Invalid taxonomy: %s.' ), $taxonomy ), '4.4.0' );
                continue;
            }

            // array = hierarchical, string = non-hierarchical.
            if ( is_array( $tags ) ) {
                $tags = array_filter( $tags );
            }

            // remove the capability check here
            wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $tags, $taxonomy );
        }
    }
```

Pay attention to the end of the code where I removed the `current_user_can` check.

Now you can use the `wp post create` command to create your posts with custom taxonomies attached.

**REMEMBER TO REVERT THE CHANGES BEFORE YOU USE THE SITE AGAIN!**